# traefik 1.7.11 subdomain based access rules setup

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, kube-dns, traefik-ingress

I want to create IP based subdomain access rules for traefik (1.7.11) ingress controller running on Kubernetes (EKS). All IP's are allowed to talk to an external/frontend entry point

```
traefik.toml: |
  defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]
  logLevel = "INFO"
  [entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
      compress = true
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.http.whiteList]
      sourceRange = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
      compress = true
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [entryPoints.https.whiteList]
      sourceRange = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

But we have only `prod` environments running in this cluster.

Want to limit certain endpoints like `monitoring.domain.com` accessible from limited IP's (Office location) and keep `*.domain.com` (default) accessible from the public internet.

anyway I can do it in `traefik` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "x.x.x.x/x, xxxx::/x"` [Traefik annotation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#annotations) on you [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) object. You can also have 4 Ingress objects. One for each `stage.domain.com`, `qa.domain.com`, `dev.domain.com` and `prod.domain.com`.

For anything other than `prod.domain.com` you can add a whitelist.

Another option is to change your `traefik.toml` with [`[entryPoints.http.whitelist]`](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#white-listing) but you may have to have different ingress controllers with a different [ingress class](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#between-traefik-and-other-ingress-controller-implementations) for each environment.